# Apply a formula to two rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
intakeNo                         1                    2                    3   
intakeDate                  3/21/1978            4/28/1979            1/11/1981
intakeAmt                   9.3E-04              5.1E-02              2.4E-04   
intakeSD                    2.2E-02              7.7E-01              5.8E-03   
incident                          F                    F                    F                    
intakeDate                  3/19/1978            5/6/1979             1/3/1981
intakeAmt                   3.2E-02              1.9E-02              4.7E-03   
intakeSD                    9.6E-01              5.3E-01              1.4E-01
```

I could get the average of say intakeAmt by

```
df.loc['intakeAmt_avg'] = df.loc['intakeAmt'].mean()
```

But, I would like to apply the following function to get the average of the intakeDates in the dataframe, and add a row called, say intakeDate_avg:

```
def average_of_two_dates(datestr1, datestr2):
    a = dt.datetime.strptime(datestr1, '%m/%d/%Y')
    b = dt.datetime.strptime(datestr2, '%m/%d/%Y')
    ave = a+(b-a)/2
    return dt.datetime.strftime(ave, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

First, I have tried transposing the 'intakeDate' slice of the df:

```
a = df['intakeDate']
b = a.T
```

which gives me the following dataframe b:

```
intakeNo   intakeDate  intakeDate                     
1          3/21/1978   3/19/1978
2          4/28/1979    5/6/1979
3          1/11/1981    1/3/1981
```

Now, I need to add a column called intakeDate_avg that applies the average_of_two_dates function to the values in the two intakeDate columns.

The original transposed df looks like:

```
intakeNo    intakeDate  intakeAmt   intakeSD    incident    intakeDate  intakeAmt   intakeSD
1          3/21/1978    9.30E-04    2.20E-02    F           3/19/1978   3.20E-02    9.60E-01
2          4/28/1979    5.10E-02    7.70E-01    F           5/6/1979    1.90E-02    5.30E-01
3          1/11/1981    2.40E-04    5.80E-03    F           1/3/1981    4.70E-03    1.40E-01
```

Comment: As per the previous question of yours I answered, you should (in fact, I'd say *must*) transpose your dataframe before doing any meaningful analysis. I will have a look at this if you update with the transposed dataframe [see instructions in previous question].

Comment: Your average may work for two dates (or values in general), but won't work for, e.g., 10 values: which value is a, which is b in that case?

Comment: @jpp, I have modified my question that includes a transposed dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: @DPdl, can you transpose the input data too please? Since this is  what we'll be starting with.

Comment: @jpp, done. Thanks.

Comment: @DPdl, still need to combine the columns (as in the previous post), i.e. you should have 2 `intakeDate` columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your function to work with a single list input, you can use `apply` in this case:

```
df.loc['intakeDate_avg'] = df.loc['intakeDate'].apply(average_of_two_dates)
```